# Can Rails Active Records migrate Entries without a primary key?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, migration, rails-activerecord

I'm well aware of why one might want primary keys, and also aware about why rails uses primary keys for processing in batched transactions.

However, I have a particular table for which data is correlated on an indexed key which is not unique. Further, data is never updated, but only dropped (logging data).

What I want to know is, is there a blocking (synchronous) alternative to `Record.all.each` which can be used on records without a primary key?

To be clear: there is a good reason the data doesn't have a primary key, so any solution involving adding a primary key is not what I'm after.

Code example:

```
Data::A.find_all.each do |x|
    new_entry = Data::B.create()

    [:correlating_value_non_unique, :some, :other, :stuff].each do |y|
        new_entry.update_attribute(y, x.read_attribute(y))
    end

    new_entry.save!
end
```

Comment: I'm inferring a couple of things, but first know that Record.all.each is really just Record.find(:all).each.   You can give the find method a :lock => false solution or otherwise make your retrievals readonly which I think is what you're trying to do.

Comment: As far as I can tell, that unfortunately doesn't solve the problem. If the active record has *no* primary key, it still fails. If the data model file has a fake primary key (which isn't unique), the migration also fails. It seems to me that this makes sense, as locking the transaction or not doesn't necessarily mean the transaction should not run in batches (which is the real cause of this issue, as far as I can tell). Thanks for the input, though.